# How to create file in java

Tags: string, file, if-statement, filereader

```
File Name = new File("G:/Java/lesson25_1/Name.txt");

if(Name==null){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Details are missing");
}

try{

    FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("Name.txt");

    BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(fr1);

    String str=br1.readLine();

    br1.close();
```

when i do this in a method it dosn't work when i click the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method for file called `exists` to check if the given file exist or not.

```
String path = "G:/Java/lesson25_1/Name.txt";
File file = new File(path);

if(!file.isFile() || !file.canRead()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Details are missing");
} else {
    try {

        FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("Name.txt");
        BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(fr1);

        String str=br1.readLine();

        br1.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Further reading into the docs, you should use `isFile()` instead, `exists()` will return true if the path is a directory. I have edited my solution. @Dany123